# sugarcrm users insert in magento

Tags: magento, sugarcrm, suitecrm

Hi  I have a sugarcrm instance and magento instance they two are separate 
i mean they have different databases.  My requirement is when i create a user in the sugarcrm ,it should also insert the admin users in magento  How can i do that in sugar,where the code has to be executed in sugar. Any other way is a

Answer (score 2):

I would have to do some research on the Magento API, but in Sugar, you would want to create a logic hook in the Users module that triggers 'after_save'. You would point it to a custom class/method you've created that would use Magento's API for creating a new user.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use logic hooks and "after_save" will work for you. So add a logic in after_save. Write you code in simple PHP which will get data from Sugar bean fields and will create Magento user accordingly. Read this link for logic hook: http://support.sugarcrm.com/Documentation/Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_7.9/Architecture/Logic_Hooks/#Module_Hooks